# JavaScript cancel function

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling

I have some code where I have a timer. Every 3 seconds the background changes colors, and when you hover the stop button, the color changer pauses, I have an onclick event that i am using in junction with the mouseout event but the mouseout event cancels out my onclick event. What can I do so that the onclic event works still after I move the mouse from the stop button?

Code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Usbx/)

```
<script>
var colors = new Array();
colors[0] = "green";
colors[1] = "blue";
colors[2] = "gray";
var i = 0;
var timer;

function changeOfPlans() {
    timer = setInterval("colorChange()", 3000);
}

function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    document.getElementById("two").style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    i++;
    if (i == 3 || i > 3) {
        //start over by setting i to 0
        i = 0;
    }
}

function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}​
</script>
```

Comment: Set a variable on click, then on mouse out check if that variable is set or not.

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do with the onclick? as I can't 100% understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: when you hover the thing, remove the event listener. when you leave the event, recreate the event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the on click action so that it sets a variable. Then have the mouse out first check whether that variable is set before restarting the color changing. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Usbx/2/).

I modified your JavaScript like so:

```
var stopped = false;

function changeOfPlans() {
    if (!stopped) {
        timer = setInterval("colorChange()",3000);
    }
}

function fullstop() {
  stopped = true;
  stop();
}
```

Then I updated your onclick to call `fullstop()` instead of just `stop()`. Since I left the other `stop()` function the same, the hover-to-stop-move-away-to-restart functionality still works as you had it originally. All of the other JavaScript remains the same.

```
<button type="button" onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="changeOfPlans()" onclick="fullstop()">Stop</button>
```

There are other ways of doing this -- enhzflep suggests a good one in the comments -- but this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setInterval`, so to cancel you need `clearInterval` not `clearTimeout`.
Also don't run it again on mouseout i guess:

```
onmouseout="changeOfPlans()"
```